# How to slice a string in Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

I need to send a message to a webhook. This message must contain the pair/tickers (e.g. "BTC_USDT") separated by an underline. The pair comes from `syminfo.ticker` altogether, though (e.g. "BTCUSDT").

Given that the second pair is always the same in each different alert (e.g. I will have an script for alerts with USDT pair only), and therefore I know the exact number of characters of the second ticker, how can I slice the string (or maybe `syminfo.ticker` itself?) to get only the first characters by removing the last 'n'?

E.g. In Python, one could...

```
pair = "BTCUSDT"
first = pair[:-4] # BTC
last = pair[-4:] # USDT
```

The script:

```
msg0 = str.format('"pair": "{0}"', syminfo.ticker)
msg = "{" + Msg0 + "}"
alert(msg, freq)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. **Simplest way**

   If your code allows, cnosider to concatenate the string by using something like this:

   `composedStringForAlert = syminfo.basecurrency + '_' + syminfo.currency`

2. **Answer to your question**

   Since you are explicitly asking for decomposing the given string format which likely already exists elsewhere in your script, the following two functions provided will do the job.

   (*See the declarations in the full script at the end of my answer to understand them better.*)

   ```
   composeCharsToDelete(simple string inputStr) =>
   str.contains(inputStr, ".") ? str.length(syminfo.currency)+2 : str.length(syminfo.currency)


   extractStringFromString(simple string inputStr = syminfo.ticker) =>
   result = str.length(inputStr), result>1 ? str.substring(inputStr, 0, result-composeCharsToDelete(inputStr)) : inputStr
   ```

3. **Full solution**

   For completeness and better understanding, I added the full declaration and some basic validation to e.g. ensure the script won't trigger on pairs your likely do not want e.g. BNC, BLX, BTC.D, ...).

   ```
   //@version=5

   indicator("extractStringFromString", overlay=true)

   bool IGNORELIST    = syminfo.currency == '' or syminfo.currency == 'BTC' or syminfo.currency == 'BTC' or syminfo.prefix == 'INDEX'
   bool VALID_SYMBOL  = syminfo.type == 'crypto' and not IGNORELIST

   //#region ---------------------- FUNCTIONS

   // @function                      compose a number of chars (to substract from a given string).
   //                                consider: on e.g. perpetual contracts, tradingview appends '.P' to syminfo ticker and root.
   // @param inputStr                (simple string) passed string to 'reduce'.
   // @returns                       (simple int) length of chars to substract.
   // Dependencies                   (called from user defined function) extractStringFromString
   composeCharsToDelete(simple string inputStr) =>
       str.contains(inputStr, ".") ? str.length(syminfo.currency)+2 : str.length(syminfo.currency)


   // @function                      substract a calculated amount of chars from a given string
   // @param inputStr                (simple string) priginal string to substract a calculated amount of chars from. (see 'Dependencies')
   // @returns                       (simple string) original input string reduced by #chars (from end)
   // Dependencies                   (calling user defined function) composeCharsToDelete
   extractStringFromString(simple string inputStr = syminfo.ticker) =>
       result = str.length(inputStr), result>1 ? str.substring(inputStr, 0, result-composeCharsToDelete(inputStr)) : inputStr
   //#endregion ------------------- FUNCTIONS


   //#region ------------------ PLOT TO CHART

   if barstate.islast and IGNORELIST
       runtime.error("Not a valid symbol")

   if barstate.islast and VALID_SYMBOL
       label.new(x = bar_index +1, y = open, text = extractStringFromString(), yloc = yloc.price, color = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 85), style = label.style_label_left, textcolor = color.rgb(255, 255, 255, 0), textalign = text.align_center, tooltip = syminfo.currency + '_' + syminfo.basecurrency)

   //#endregion --------------- PLOT TO CHART
   ```

Answer (score 1):

`syminfo.basecurrency` will return you the base currency for the symbol. For the symbol `BTCUSD` returns `BTC`.

If you need a function, you need to split the string with `str.split()` first to get all the chars in the string. Then loop over the chars until `len-n-1`.

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script")

f_get_first_n(str, n) =>
    char_arr = str.split(str, '')
    len_char_arr = array.size(char_arr)
    ret_val = ""

    if (n <= len_char_arr)
        for i=0 to (len_char_arr - n - 1)
            ret_val := ret_val + array.get(char_arr, i)        
    ret_val

pair = syminfo.ticker

if barstate.islast
    txt = f_get_first_n(pair, 4)
    txt2 = syminfo.basecurrency
    label.new(bar_index, high, txt + "\n" + txt2)
```